# Javascript Questions on the function - IIFE

Tags: javascript, aem

I was asked to ask another question and link it to this thread.
[How add mandatory dropdown field in Touch UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193659/how-add-mandatory-dropdown-field-in-touch-ui/37041445?noredirect=1#comment61636750_37041445)

My question is what: 
can somebody tell me what is the end line of the javascript function is doing.

```
})(document, Granite.$, Granite.author);
```

is it some kind of namespacing.

For your reference i am attaching the Javascript code.

```
(function (document, $, ns) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).on("click", ".cq-dialog-submit", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this).closest("form.foundation-form"),
            title = $form.find("[name='authoringMode']").val(),
            message, clazz = "coral-Button ";

        if(!title){
            ns.ui.helpers.prompt({
            title: Granite.I18n.get("Invalid Input"),
            message: "Please Check Values",
                actions: [{
                    id: "CANCEL",
                    text: "CANCEL",
                    className: "coral-Button"
                }
            ],
            callback: function (actionId) {
                if (actionId === "CANCEL") {
                }
            }
        });
        }else{
                 $form.submit();
        }
    });
})(document, Granite.$, Granite.author);
```

Comment: Please  improve the subject line. As written it will not help anybody in the future with  the same problem find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we otherwise call a self-invoking function:

```
(function (document, $, ns) { ...
})(document, Granite.$, Granite.author);
```

and those ("document, Granite...etc) are arguments being passed to that very same function.

Answer (score 1):

The last line is passing arguments to the IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression). You can learn more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Comment: Thanks everyone Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
})(document, Granite.$, Granite.author);
```

passes parameters to function, defining `document` as `document`, `Granite.$` as `$` and `Granite.author` as `ns` within the function expression at

```
(function (document, $, ns) {
```

---

e.g.,

```js
var obj = {
  $:jQuery,
  author:"abc"
};

(function(document, $, ns) { 
  "use strict";
  
  console.log($, ns)
 
}(document, obj.$, obj.author))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't explain why it is done so nor shows where it can be learnt

Comment: @Yerken _"doesn't explain why it is done so"_ ? See post at _"passes parameters to function, defining `document` as `document`, `Granite.$` as `$` and `Granite.author` as `ns` within the function expression"_ The process passes parameters to function, as described at post. What do you mean by  _"nor shows where it can be learnt"_ ? stacksnippets demonstrates example `js` having same pattern as appears at original Question.