# AEM 6.1 Touch UI Dialog - invoke dialog validation event manually

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, dialog, aem

I have some callback on dialog-submited event and I want to find out way to guarantee that dialog will be submitted after my callback (the validation after my callback can inhibit me). Can I pre validate manually whole dialog (every widget) if I'm not aware how much widgets exist on dialog. Maybe there is something in order to invoke this validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AEM has made a few methods available to you through a jQuery plugin:

```
$input.willValidate()
$input.checkValidity()
$input.validationMessage()
$input.setCustomValidity(errorMessage)
$input.updateErrorUI()
```

For your particular requirement, you can get all the fields in the form, loop through them and check their validity. Use a jQuery selector to find all the form fields; you might have a custom CSS class name on your field elements or you might have a custom Class name on your form for example.

```
function validateForm() {
    var valid = true;

    /* Select the form fields, will be project specific. */
    var $formFields = $('.dialog-selector .coral-Form-field');

    $formFields.each(function(){
        if (!$(this).checkValidity()) {
            valid = false;

            /* Break out of each loop */
            return false;
        }
    });

    return valid;
}
```

See this blog post regarding [AEM Touch UI Validation](http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2016/02/aem-touch-ui-custom-validation) and this [AEM Touch UI Validation Library](https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-touch-ui-validation) on GitHub for more examples.

Comment: Would you mind to check your server from http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2016/02/aem-touch-ui-custom-validation ? The request answers with a 503 server error.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this Adobe Helpx article:
Link:- https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-validate.html
//Validating Adobe Experience Manager Touch UI dialog values

Step 1:  Create a component under /apps/

Step 2: Create cq:dialog for touch UI dialog and all the items required.

Step 3: Create clientlibs under the component folder. Add ‘cq.authoring.dialog‘ as categories. This enables to use all the functions available in Granite UI.

Step 4: Add a script which has the validation logic using JQuery (ex: validation.js). Make sure you add that js in the js.txt file

Code:-

```
(function (document, $, ns) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).on("click", ".cq-dialog-submit", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this).closest("form.foundation-form"),
            emailid = $form.find("[name='./email']").val(),
               message, clazz = "coral-Button ",
         patterns = {
             emailadd: /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i
        };

        if(emailid != "" && !patterns.emailadd.test(emailid) && (emailid != null)) {
                ns.ui.helpers.prompt({
                title: Granite.I18n.get("Invalid Input"),
                message: "Please Enter a valid Email Address",
                actions: [{
                    id: "CANCEL",
                    text: "CANCEL",
                    className: "coral-Button"
                }],
            callback: function (actionId) {
                if (actionId === "CANCEL") {
                }
            }
        });

        }else{
                 $form.submit();
        }
    });
})(document, Granite.$, Granite.author);
```

Please read full article, it will tell you step by step approach to achieve the needful.

Some Reference Adobe Community Posts are:-
Link:- http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__wfdy-i_have_gonethroughh.html

Link:- http://adobeaemclub.com/aem-touch-ui-dialog-validation/

**Great Link:- http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2016/02/aem-touch-ui-custom-validation**

I hope this will help you.

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It sounds like he wants to check if fields validate rather than creating new validation rules. If that's the case, he  can use `$.fn.checkValidity()` as detailed in my answer. Regardless, this isn't the best way to create validation rules, use `$.validator.register()` for custom validators. Side note, use `$(window).adaptTo("foundation-ui")` to create alerts and prompts. I've detailed adding custom validators in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35904476/3022863).

Comment: Thak you, your article is really awesome:- http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2016/02/aem-touch-ui-custom-validation